# JQuery Slide & Toggle Issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slide, slidetoggle

I have a website which uses JQuery to show a hidden div when a button is clicked. I was using a toggle method and all was working correctly, but I want to change it so that it only shows, but when the button is clicked, the div shows and slides down but then quickly hides again.

Here is my Toggle code which works correctly:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(function() {
    $('#menuButton').toggle(function() {
        $('#menuArea').slideDown();
        }, function() {
        $('#menuArea').slideUp();
    });
    return false;
});
</script>
```

And here is the No Toggle which hides again:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(function() {
    $('#menuButton').click(function() {
        $('#menuArea').slideDown("fast");
    });
    return false;
});
</script>
```

Any ideas why this is?

Comment: The version of `toggle` you're using has been deprecated and removed from jQuery a few years ago.

Comment: Yeah I worked out that the `return false` was in the wrong place. Toggle works with the JQuery version that I'm using, and I'm hosting the JQuery script on my server so all should be fine right?

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? I'd made a codepen and works in Chrome, Safari and FF http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GZPWxw